# How can I get file icons on Windows asynchronously (and ideally in parallel) from C++?

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous

The [MSDN documentation for SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says, quite rightly:

> You should call this function from a background thread. Failure to do so could cause the UI to stop responding.

so I'm trying to figure out a good way to do this where I have a large list (80+) of them to do, and would like to parallelize the underlying I/O.  I could use a thread-pool, but I'm not an expert Windows programmer, so I was wondering if there was a better technique for this.

Comment: Fairly pointless.  This is throttled by disk I/O, not CPU cores.  Threads will just take turn waiting for the disk.

Comment: The Windows I/O scheduler seems to do well enough here in my testing, at least with modern drives.  I suspect it's because keeping the read queue full lets it pick up data on every rotation, but even if it's a wash on I/O it will let me do computation on the data while waiting for the next I/O.  And then there are network drives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a queue of file names to process (a linked list would suffice; consider STL's std::list). Create a lock for that queue (a critical section would do). Spawn a bunch of threads (2-4). Each thread would acquire the lock, get the head from the queue, release the lock and retrieve the icon - in the loop. If no more items in the queue, the thread quits. Something like this.

Comment: Yeah, I could use a thread-pool (as I said in the question, but perhaps not clearly).  For I/O on Windows, though, generally things that lead to WaitFor*Object are nicer to work with, and have lower overhead.

Comment: One should use `std::queue` or `std::deque` for this, not a linked list. The only point of using the linked list would have been to make it lock free, but the STL's `std::list` 's iterators are not lock free, sort of defeating the point.

Comment: WaitForXXX calls block the thread that does the waiting. Defeats the purpose of spinning the background thread (unless it's MsgWaitForMultipleObjects with a short timeout). Better to deliver messages from worker threads to the UI thread in Windows messages, or something like that. APC calls might also work, but then again, you need to modify the main thread's message loop for that.

Comment: Yeah, I would have one thread wait on multiple objects.  What I'm asking for (or trying to) is a way to do icon fetching without a thread per active icon fetch.  (There may not be one.)

Comment: No way as long as you're using SHGetFileInfo. Short of reading and parsing PE files by hand (i. e. via CreateFile/ReadFile), I don't know of any async methods. But worry not, icon extraction is a fairly short process with local disc files (whole another store via the network). You're way overengineering.

Answer (score 0):

Making parallel I/O calls might not give you any speed up (likely only an overhead). You can experiment with GBL library and see if threading helps you. Write handler functions to respond to events. Then you can easily switch between AsyncHandler, which uses thread pool and Handler, which is synchronous to see if you can achieve any speedup.

Comment: In a bunch of my other I/O tests I get speedups through 8x parallelism at least on similar file patterns, which is why I'm interested in this in the first place. :-)  GBL is an interesting library, though, thanks for the pointer!