# Asynchronously get a file's icon with .NET Framework

Tags: .net, file, asynchronous, io, icons

I'm noticing that [System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon?view=netframework-4.8) takes quite a while with a large number of files, and since it's synchronous it freezes the UI even if I'm doing something clever like keeping a dictionary of previously-seen file extensions.

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694234/faster-way-to-get-associated-icon) suggests another way, which is also synchronous in nature, using [SHGetFileInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa), but [this question about using that function with native C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595796/how-can-i-get-file-icons-on-windows-asynchronously-and-ideally-in-parallel-fro) has some commenters that allude to its potential for asynchronous use.

Is there a way to get a file's icon in a purely-asynchronous manner, i.e. by letting the disk controller do the work, freeing up my threads for other work?  Or am I forced to use `Task.Run` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can take, depending on your needs.

Last time I did this, I built a cache of icons on start-up, walking through each extension type from the registry (or static list defined somewhere else). This is probably the simplest approach. If this slows startup too much you can have it as a background task, with anything that requires the cache waiting for it to be built.

You can of course create a task as you suggest, whenever you require an icon. I would still cache the task in a dictionary, so that you're not doing multiple lookups for the same icon.